# What is the probability of winning the game "one,two,three"?

Tags: probability

There is a game going around my school that plays with the following rules:

- The game is played by a single player
  -The game is played using a deck of italian gaming card ( $40$ cards, $4$ suit, every suit has cards going from the value of $1$ to the value of $10$ )
- The player has to draw cards continuously.
- Every time the player draws a card he has to say a value starting from $1$ and increasing the value every draw. After saying $3$ the value becomes $1$ again.
- If the player draws a card with the same value as the value said before drawing (ex:  the player says "one" and draws an ace) the game stops and the player loses.
- If the player can't draw anymore cards the game stops and the player wins.

---

What I want to calculate is the probability of the player winning. Unfortunately it seems I can' t get to answer.

**So, what is the probability for a player A to win?**

Comment: A simulation gets about 0.008 as the probability of winning, let me see.